# I want to execute a script (.sh file) on startup so that I can set the sensitivity of my mouse. How can I do this?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sh, ubuntu-14.04

Basically, I want to be able to have a script run on startup.

The script I want to run is:

```
#!/bin/sh
xinput --set-prop 13 "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 1.3
```

I tried putting the script in `/etc/init.d` like other threads suggested but this did not run the script. I have `chmod` it to `+x` as well.

Does anybody have any suggestions as how to get this to run on startup?

Thank you

Comment: You could [make it a startup script in Unity](http://askubuntu.com/questions/462143/where-are-the-startup-scripts-for-unity-desktop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the following in ~/.profile  which is executed only when you log in with a graphic interface:

```
source /path/to/script.sh
```

or simply copy in it:

```
xinput --set-prop 13 "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 1.3
```

Comment: Note that this will make the script execute every time you open a shell, which means with every Terminal you open, and even if you log in without a GUI via a TTY login or remotely via SSH.

Comment: @memecs So I need to copy my script to `~/.bash_profile`?

Comment: @memecs I am also unable to find the cat `~/.bash_profile`. I try to `cd` to it and it says the directory can not be found. I am very new to linux, so sorry if this is a really obvious question.

Comment: @memecs Oh got that reversed with `.bashrc` in my head, my mistake.

Comment: @crossboy007. If .bash_profile doesn't exist simply create it in your home directory.

Comment: @crossboy007: Actually it's .profile which is executed only when you log in with a graphic interface (such as gnome or unity.)

Comment: @ajp15243. See my correction, .profile is the right file.

Comment: @memecs So I need to coppy my .sh sscript to ` ~/.profile`. and this will only be executed when I log into Linux from the system Locally? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, put 'xinput --set-prop 13 "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 1.3
' in .profile.

Comment: @memes Oh right, so not the source to where the script is? Thats what I understood from your answer? Thanks

Comment: @memecs Oh right, ok. Got it working. Thanks. Is there any way to make the script run on the actual startup so I don't have to wait until I login for the script to run? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use following steps to execute your script on startup

1. Create your file in **/etc/init.d** location. Here the format of the file is important

   ## !/bin/bash

   ## Source function library.

   . /etc/init.d/functions

   start() {
       # Here you write your script that should be executed on start up
   }

   stop() {
       # This get called by kill scripts
   }

   case "$1" in
       start)
          start
          ;;
       stop)
          stop
          ;;
       restart)
          stop
          start
          ;;
       status)
          # This is optional
          ;;
       *)
          echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart}"
   esac

   exit 0
2. After first step is done , you create a symbolic link in **/etc/rc3.d/** which will point to above script
   ex: if some_script is your script name link should be created like
     **ln -s ../init.d/some_script S01some_script**
   If you want somethings to be executed on shutdown time you may create a link with capital K this is called as kill script

Thanks,
Sudhir

Comment: So I just need to coppy my .sh script to the directory `/etc/rc3.d/` and have the first letter of it as a capital 'S'? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I really am new to linux, so can I just confirm with you. Make a script called whatever I want and put it in `/etc/init.d`. This script could follow the format you included above (could I confirm that I include the line in bold which says `Source function library.`. Once I have made the script and saved it in this location I should next `cd` to `/etc/rc3.d/`. Once in this directory I should run the following line: `ln -s ../init.d/some_script S01some_script` replacing the first and second `some_script` with the name of my script in `/etc/init.d`? Each time my PC boots this will run?